# How to write Aggregate pattern in Scala?

Tags: design-patterns, scala, aggregate-functions

Suppose I have `Iterator[A]`(**size is infinite**) and I want to get `Iterator[B]` from it where some subsequent values of type A are aggregated.

Example:
I have list of strings:

```
Iterator(
    "START",
    "DATA1",
    "DATA2",
    "DATA3",
    "START",
    "DATA1",
    "DATA2",
    //.. 10^10 more records
)
```

I want to join strings from START to NEXT START excluding. I.e. write parser.

```
Iterator(
"START DATA1 DATA2 DATA3",
"START DATA1 DATA2",
    //.. 10^10 / 5 more records
)
```

I know how to do this imperatively, but I want to accomplish it with scala higher order functions. Any ideas?

PS EIP Aggregate http://camel.apache.org/aggregator2.html.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want a functional solution, you should use Streams rather than iterators (streams are immutable). Here's one possible approach:

```
def aggregate(strs: Stream[String] ) = { 
  aggregateRec( strs )
}

def aggregateRec( strs: Stream[String] ): Stream[String] = {
  val tail = strs.drop(1)
  if( tail.nonEmpty ) {
    val (str, rest ) = accumulate( tail )
    Stream.cons( str, aggregateRec( rest ) )
  }
  else Stream.empty
}

def accumulate( strs: Stream[String] ): (String, Stream[String])  = {
  val first = "START " + strs.takeWhile( _ != "START").mkString(" ")
  val rest = strs.dropWhile( _ != "START" )
  ( first, rest )
}
```

It works as expected:

```
val strs = Stream( "START", "1", "2", "3", "START", "A", "B" )
val strs2 = aggregate( strs )
strs2 foreach println
```

Comment: I'm confused a bit.  If the underlying implementation of the iterator is a Stream then why wouldn't it suffice?  i.e. why would we use a Stream explicitly when we can just use an Iterator and, if that Iterator happens to iterate over a Stream, then fine?

Comment: Because iterators are mutable. Calling `next` changes the iterator state. I just wanted to provide a fully functional solution.

Comment: Ah, fair enough.  Thx.  I was just making sure that there wasn't something more sinister I was missing.

Comment: With streams it is also possible to make unbounded look ahead. So solution with streams is more robost, thanks.

Comment: Be careful of running out of memory.  Memoization in streams can quickly eat up a ton of memory for no reason (i.e. in the case where you're not interested in history).

Answer (score 5):

Well, an infinite stream changes things rather dramatically.  Assuming I understand the rest of your situation, this should work:

```
def aggregate(it: Iterator[String]) = new Iterator[String] {
  if (it.hasNext) it.next
  def hasNext = it.hasNext
  def next = "START " + (it.takeWhile(_ != "START")).mkString(" ")
}
```

So that you can:

```
val i = aggregate(yourStream.iterator)
i.take(20).foreach(println) // or whatever
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try it with a fold:

```
val ls = List(
  "START",
  "DATA1",
  "DATA2",
  "DATA3",
  "START",
  "DATA1",
  "DATA2"
)

(List[List[String]]() /: ls) { (acc, elem) =>
  if (elem == "START")
    List(elem) :: acc // new head list
  else
    (elem :: acc.head) :: acc.tail // prepend to current head list
} map (_.reverse mkString " ") reverse;
```

Comment: Cool, but I've added restriction that ls is infinite Stream/Iterator. So fold will not work here

Comment: Not cool adding further restrictions after the question is asked…

Comment: Sorry for that, I've added them because it was actually my problem. I want to write parser for very large log file. I just forgot that it is clear to me onlyю

Answer (score 0):

With Streams:

```
object Iter {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val es = List("START", "DATA1", "DATA2", "START", "DATA1", "START")
    val bit = batched(es.iterator, "START")
    println(bit.head.toList)
    println(bit.tail.head.toList)
  }

  def batched[T](it: Iterator[T], start: T) = { 
    def nextBatch(): Stream[List[T]] = { 
      (it takeWhile { _ != start }).toList match {
        case Nil => nextBatch()
        case es => Stream.cons(start :: es, nextBatch())
      }
    }
    nextBatch()
  }

}
```